# How to set up robust RAID 6?

Tags: centos, software-raid

Perhaps I'm going about this all the wrong way, but I am having chronic trouble managing a RAID6 software array in CENTOS7.

The system has an internal pair of drives (2x500GB) in RAID1 which has been bulletproof so far. I have another 5 external drives (5x1TB) in an enclosure over eSATA through an eSATA PCIe expansion card. These are all in RAID0 which has been consistent from the start. I have another 5 disk enclosure (also 5x1TB, same make/model/age) on a second eSATA PCI expansion card (same make/model) with whose disks I have attempted to set up in RAID6 (4 active, 1 spare).

A first failure occurred when the power was cut and one of the drives failed to come back to the array. I eventually just wiped the drive and its partition, then re-added it to the array. The array was after a rebuild back up to full strength and I did a full scan/refresh/rewrite to get everything consistent. Last night after about 30GB of writes, the array goes down, three of the four active drives seem to have gone away. Any attempt to reassemble suggests that the array cannot start with only one drive. I can `mdadm --examine` all of the participant drives and they all successfully show the correct array GUID, RAID device count, array name, have a good checksum, raid level and show as having an active state. Each of them shows however a different Array State:

```
/dev/sdg/   ...A
/dev/sdh/   AAAA
/dev/sdi/   AA.A
/dev/sdj/   .A.A
```

`mdadm --assemble --scan --guid=<guid>` yields the same response as the 'Disks' GUI in CENTOS, i.e. 'assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.'

What am I doing wrong in administering this array and how do I go about recovery?

**Edit:**
I cannot see any record of the /dev/md126 that was the device, so I cannot use any functions that interact with that 'name'.

**Update:**
With no additional information to work from (no logs were readable), I attempted the `--force` as suggested in the comment. After initially starting up in a 'degraded' state with a missing disk and going into 'rebuilding', I used `--examine` on all drives and one, /dev/sdh was not participating 'AA.A'. I attempted to add the drive to the array though `mdadm --add` but got the wrong array to add it to: the new array came up both as /dev/md126 and /dev/md126p1, I'm not sure what the difference is but it is the p1 that seems to be active. I cancelled the rebuild operation and restarted it again with the same command including `--force` the md came up with no data. I cancelled that and tried one more time. Now the data is visible again on the drive and /dev/sdh is participating ('AAAA'). The drive is in 'recovering' mode and appears to be using all four drives.

Fortunately the data on the array is backed up so I have the luxury of being a bit cavalier to try to learn something..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a drive is kicked from a RAID array, its metadata is no longer updated. So the drive that still sees all drives as `AAAA` is usually the one that was kicked first. The `update time` might reflect that as well.

So I assume the RAID layer first kicked `sdh` (when 4 drives were active), then `sdi` (with 3 drives), `sdj` (two drives), and that leaves `sdg` alone with just one drive.

If the disks are not actually faulty, you might try your luck with `--assemble --force`. Check the update times and use the two drives that are most recent, then re-add the drives that were kicked first, and hope that the RAID will re-sync.

You should check your `dmesg` / system logs to ascertain as to why the drives were kicked in the first place and then make sure it does not happen again. Software RAID works well in general, but it's very important to have intact disks, test disks for errors regularly, and rule out any issues with your cables/controllers/power supply.

Comment: You're right, the `mdadm --examine` update time does go in the sequence you suggested, each about 10 minutes apart... I haven't tried the `--assemble --force` yet, looking around some more. `dmesg | grep -i raid` doesn't show anything interesting and the CENTOS7 log viewer is broken. Any idea where to find the raw log file for RAID?